# My grid column drops in to multiple line instead of single

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a grid system using the class name. for that I have divided a row in to 2 column. once I do that, 2 column converted as 2 rows. how to prevent this?

I am trying to create a library approach. so people can use the mixed columns for their needs.

```css
.grid{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap:10px;
}

.column-6{
  border:1px solid red;
  grid-column:1/6;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column-6">colunm 50%</div>
  <div class="column-6">column 50%</div>
</div>
```

Here I am keeping default as 12fr, it divided in to 2 columns. but shows me as 2 rows. is any alignment or wrapping property need to be added?

Thanks in advance.

**update**

I tried like adding this properties:

```
.column-6{
  border:1px solid red;
  grid-column:1/6;
  grid-row:1/1;
}
```

but both are merging to gathered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to use `span 6`. By setting `1/6` you explicitely set the start and end line whereas you only need to specify the number of columns and keep the placement auto:

```css
.grid{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap:10px;
}

.column-6{
  border:1px solid red;
  grid-column:span 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column-6">colunm 50%</div>
  <div class="column-6">column 50%</div>
  <div class="column-6">colunm 50%</div>
  <div class="column-6">column 50%</div>
</div>
```